# Запятые при перечислении эпитетов. Что если эпитеты будут составными?

Tags: пунктуация

У него были трусливые блуждающие глаза. Запятая не нужна, верно?
А если... У него были трусливые бессмысленно блуждающие глаза?
А если... У него были слегка трусливые абсолютно бессмысленно блуждающие по сторонам глаза?

В какой ситуации запятая все-таки понадобится? Ведь эпитетов по сути все равно два. Есть ли какое-то правило для таких ситуаций?

Answer (score 3):

Такое чувство, что *трусливые, блуждающие* — однородные члены предложения, запятая нужна. Определения характеризуют предмет с одной стороны: слова *блуждающие и трусливые* близки по смыслу, хотя это не одно и то же, конечно.

*У него были трусливые, блуждающие глаза.*

*У него были трусливые, бессмысленно блуждающие глаза*

*У него были слегка трусливые, абсолютно бессмысленно блуждающие по сторонам глаза.*

Кроме того, последнее предложение, на мой взгляд,  страдает речевой избыточностью, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Спасибо. А если изначальная фраза будет "трусливые зеленые глаза"?

Comment: Тогда запятая не нужна, конечно. Это неоднородные определения.

Answer (score 0):

*У него были трусливые(,) блуждающие глаза.* Я бы сказал, что запятая возможна, но не обязательна. Я бы не поставил.

*У него были трусливые, бессмысленно блуждающие глаза* — а вот здесь, конечно, обязательна.